# Can't seem to get a door hinge tight which is causing a door that won't latch

Tags: doors, studs, hinges, latches

This is interior door that sits around 4 inches from the nearest perpendicular wall. We had a contractor put it in around 3 years ago and it was fine until this past month. The latch no longer lines up, and I believe it is due to the door sagging a bit downwards as I can get it to latch still if I pull up on the knob (although it takes a lot of force). As you can see in the image the hinge is not fully in its groove.

I saw a few articles saying that replacing the screws with longer ones could help with this. I removed the 3/4" screws and grabbed some #10 x 2.25" screws and replaced all three screws in the top hinge, the middle one was nice and right, the top and bottom felt like they would spin forever. I used a GRK R4 screw which isn't threaded the top third or so I had suspicions that I didn't actually reach a stud with those ones. The issue was resolved for about 3 days. I found some 4 inch of the same style screw and those two still don't bite. Where should I go from here?
[image: Main hinge in question, you can see it separating from the wall due to only the middle screw being solid]

Comment: A door frame is about 3/4 inch, then an air gap with shims, then stud.  Any screw over an inch should touch a stud in a wall built normally.  Are you driving the screws in till just tight or do you go He-man on them?

Comment: Or the holes are stripped?

Comment: You might be off-angle enough that you’ve just hit the edge of the stud with the two loose ones. Try angling inwards. (You may have to predrill to make that work.)

Comment: @crip659 I'm driving them manually with a screwdriver and not putting much pressure, they don't get tight at all even with the 4 inch screws.

Comment: I think that @aloysius might be onto something. I attempted to drive it in at 30 degrees and it straightens itself back out before it ever gets tight, do I go steeper and go He-Man on the screws keeping it at an angle?

Comment: @Huesmann I do know the bottom one was with the short screw, but top was still decently tight. I replaced with the 4 inch and it just spun. I tried to toothpick trick with the short screws but there's not enough holding power to fix the sag.

Comment: This seems odd.  It would be nice to see what is happening inside of the frame/wall.  The 2 and half inch screws should have fixed the problem, unless hit the edge.  The stud edge should 1/2 inch in from the surface of the drywall.

Comment: Definitely predrill to get a slight angle without the screw trying to walk itself back into the old hole.  A 1/8” or slightly smaller bit will do.

Comment: @Aloysius had the right idea. I used a 1/8" drill bit and even though it was almost as deep as it could go (about 1.5 inches) I was able to make a tiny pilot hole in the stud which appeared to be at about a 20 degree angle and used my drill at a low speed to drive it in 90% and then finished it off with a normal screwdriver. I did not torque it down super hard but it seems the piece the hinges sit in has somewhat tucked now flush with the trim in as seen [here](https://i.imgur.com/HwG2F8T.jpg). Is this going to be an issue? The door opens and closes perfectly so far.